# Once an image is uploaded to parse.com, can I point a different domain name at it (rather than http://files.parsetfss.com/blah/blah)?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a mobile app that uploads images to parse.com.

I can reference the photo with a URL that looks like:

```
http://files.parsetfss.com/<BigLongHexString>/tfss<BigLongHexString>-Photo
```

BUT, for a variety of reasons, I'd like to be able to refer to that image using a different domain name so it would look more like

```
http://www.mydomainname.com/<BigLongHexString>/tfss<BigLongHexString>-Photo
```

Can this be done?  I just attempted it by creating a CNAME record to redirect *.mydomainname.com to files.parsetfss.com but the result was:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>www.mydomainname.com</BucketName>
<RequestId>9B3C39803AABE102</RequestId>
<HostId>
5XbotEGZP/t03kgr8FkmKvyLTHN6ZBhoRcrmXU7pBn1yz1TngkulQ/RSRuAqgBxm
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Has anyone accomplished this?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible, at least the way you are trying to do it, since the files are actually stored on Amazon S3 buckets. Your domain isn't the one setup on those buckets you will get this error.

If you are using parse hosting (https://www.parse.com/docs/hosting_guide#webapp) and your domain is set point to it you can create a route to handle the redirect from there by returning the corresponding parsetfss urls in the route.

Comment: I wasn't able to accomplish this through just DNS.  I had to create a very simple server-side script to present the image by parsing the URL and presenting the image in HTML.